# Getting all alerts for an application

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Is it possible to get all alarms, set-up by the application?
The API doesn't give any clue on that topic, it provides only means to set-up or to cancel events, but this is not enough for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could save all your alarms and their metadata into `local storage` (for example, `SQLite` database).
Then, restore that data when you need and modify system alarms via [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: That would be my plan B, but it is not sufficient: data duplication can lead to synch-issues.

Comment: For removing alarms it's not a problem because `cancel` method removes all of them. For adding alarms you could add `isAdded` column into `SQLite` table, which will indicate that alarm was successfully added.